# How to delete a Cloud Storage file after it has been downloaded?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a Cloud Function that deletes the file from Cloud Storage

Function:

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const storage = new Storage();

let handler = async (file, context) => {
    console.log(`  Event: ${context.eventId}`);
    console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
    console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
    console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);

    let bucket = storage.bucket(file.bucket);
    let bucketFile = bucket.file(file.name);

    bucketFile.delete();
};
```

I want to trigger this function after any file in the bucket is downloaded.

I've looked at the Cloud Storage triggers,

```
google.storage.object.finalize (default)

google.storage.object.delete

google.storage.object.archive

google.storage.object.metadataUpdate
```

but they don't work the way I want them to. Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

If I need to explain a little more what I want to do; Whether registered in our system or not, users are given links with some of their data openly to the public. Since these links may contain sensitive data, I would like to be granted a one-time download right. After a single download, the data needs to be permanently deleted.

Comment: Can you please share some context of your goal, i. e. why do you want to delete objects on download? It looks like there are no triggers or pub/sub events that respond to object download, however, depending on your goal, there might be some existing solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to use Object lifecycle, you can automatically delete an object after it creation for 1 day (days are the minimum unit)

You can find the Lifecycle setting in the bucket details page:

[image]

And then you have to add a rule like that for deleting objects after 1 day:

[image]

Comment: Hey Mehdi, thanks for your response. But I think the policy you mentioned only prevents the files from being deleted for a while. It doesn't delete automatically. At least as far as I've tested. Do I need to lock it, maybe? Can you give me an example?

Comment: yes you're right sorry I was meaning object lifecycle with TTL feature check this : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle   I am editing the answer

Comment: I think I can set a life cycle to delete the files after the retention policy ended. But I see min. age is 1 day. How can I make get the file get deleted in 10 minutes?

Comment: if you need smaller TTL you can use signed urls that are valid for 10m: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers

That will be limiting user access to 10m and after that the lifecycle will delete all files older than 1 day

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the get event if you activate the audit logs on Cloud Storage (be careful, the audit logs on Cloud Storage can generate a lot of logs volume and can cost).

When the audit logs are activated, you can filter on that method name:

```
methodName: "storage.objects.get"
```

Of course you can add other filters on Cloud Logging, like the resourceName to filter on the bucket and/or the file prefix/suffix (use the `=~` for the regex expression)

When your filter is OK and you get only the entries that you expect, create a sink to PubSub, then a Push PubSub subscription to invoke your piece of code (on Cloud Functions or on Cloud Run).

You will receive the Cloud Logging JSON entry, get the resourceName in the JSON to know which file has been downloaded, and then delete it.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try this and edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solves my problem but TTL will be simpler and costs less

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer to the event driven requirement.